# Will all mailclients support stretching a 1px height image?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, newsletter

I've got the problem every developer has when building newsletters.
The designer made something not done, and the customer likes it.
So is it this time. The white box, containing the text, has a nice looking box-shadow http://puu.sh/1K98C

Using it as a background-image with repeat-y doesn't work in all clients (e.g. outlook)
But a simple solution to me looks to insert it as an image and let the browser/client stretch it like this:

```
<td width="38" valign="top" >
  <img src="http://puu.sh/1K98C" width="38" style="height: 100%" />
</td>
```

Edit: After testing in IE, I see that IE doesn't allow % to stretch images. So this isn't a solution.
Are there other workarounds to fix this problem? Or is slicing those two images to the exact length the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way around this to my knowledge is to set the shadow image height in px that is slightly bigger than what the text is. I know this isn't a very flexible option especially if you have a wysiwyg or something letting the client edit the content (as you can't guess the height needed).

Also, test in different email clients to make sure the text doesn't overflow past your set height. I've found that some email clients (Gmail) overflow the text more than others even when setting line-height.